# "hidden" package names in apache netbeans 12 using gradle

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I suspect that the way this project is developed by my team is counter-intuitive as far as gradle is concerned, however, that's not about to change any time soon.

Also... technically the location in the drop down menu points towards a missing feature/plugin or error at IDE level.

Any ideas on how to fix this, or where I would begin modding netbeans itself to fix this would be appreciated.

The only options for changing the way packages show up in the project tab, i.e. tree/reducedTree/list etc don't change anything at that level.

I feel I don't have to explain this, but those **Business Packages [java][src]** entries should show up as something like **com.sun.moon.stars** packages

Thank you.

[image: self explanatory]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at time of writing, 2020/01/18, apache netbeans can't deal with jdk8 codebases defined in gradle.

Solution is to use Netbeans 8.